# Найти в списке минимальный и максимальный элемент

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не используя функций Python (min, max и т.п.) необходимо:
   Найти в списке минимальный элемент. 
   Найти в списке максимальный элемент. 
   Найти среднее арифметическое. 
Дополнительные требования:
   Массив должен вводиться с клавиатуры. 
   Ввод должен заканчивать после введения ключевого слова “end”. 
Прочих проверок на правильность ввода данных можно не делать.
Пример ввода:
 5
 2
 end

Comment: Просто напиши три функции, которые решают по одной задаче

Comment: А какого ответа вы ожидаете? На stack overflow не решают задачки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    listOfNumbers = input('Создайте список целочисленных значений: ').split()
    listOfNumbers = [int(c) for c in listOfNumbers[:listOfNumbers.index('end')]]
    maximumElementOfList, minimumElementOfList = listOfNumbers.copy(), listOfNumbers.copy()

    #Воспользуемся методом списков sort(). Метод списков sort() — сортирует целочисленные значения списка от наименьшего числа, к большему. Где первым элементом списка minimumElementOfList будет являться минимальное целочисленное значение списка listOfNumbers.
    minimumElementOfList.sort()
    #Воспользуемся методом списков sort() и методом списков reverse(). Метод списков sort() — сортирует целочисленные значения списка от наименьшего числа, к большему. Метод списков reverse() — переворачивает список. Где первым элементом списка maximumElementOfList будет являться максимальное целочисленное значение списка listOfNumbers.
    maximumElementOfList.sort()
    maximumElementOfList.reverse()

    print('Максимальный элемент списка: ', maximumElementOfList[0], '\nМинимальный элемент 
    списка: ', minimumElementOfList[0], '\nСреднее арифметическое минимального и 
    максимального значений списка: ', maximumElementOfList[0] + minimumElementOfList[0] // 2)
```

Вывод:

Создайте список целочисленных значений: **1 2 3 4 5 end 6**
Максимальный элемент списка: **5**
Минимальный элемент списка: **1**
Среднее арифметическое минимального и максимального значений списка: **5**